# PDF with an expiration date through Latex

Tags: pdf, drm

Is it possible to get PDF file with an expiration date through Latex? I mean a PDF displayable only for a particular period of time and then if you try to open it you get only a message like "Sorry your permission is expired".

Comment: Not with `pdftex`, I guess. But I see that there are postprocessors around that provide the feature.

Comment: It might also depend on the PDF viewer being used. Not all viewers implements the security features used by, say, Adobe. So you may end up with something that is expired in Adobe Reader nut not in some other PDF viewer.

Comment: Trying to add DRM to unencrypted content doesn't really work in practice.

Comment: Sorry, but I'm sort-of inclined to vote this as off-topic. Maybe it should be on SuperUser.com?

Comment: @Brent.Longborough I don't think it is off-topic. I take it the question means 'is it possible with TeX etc.?' and the answer seems to be 'no'. That is on-topic as far as I can see. (Whether a question is on-topic or not ought not depend on the answer to the question.) EDIT: With certain exceptions to avoid dangers of infinite regress and vicious circularity. 'Is this question on-topic?' is surely off-topic despite the dependence of that on the answer to the question.

Comment: @cfr: As stated, the question is not related to TeX. IMNSHO it would be on-topic if it presented a technique for PDFs and asked how to produce PDFs with these features with TeX.

Comment: @MartinSchröder I agree that if the OP had not clarified the question, it would have had to be considered off-topic. But I would not, personally, have been inclined to vote to close it as such until the OP had had that opportunity. (If the question were asking how to create PDFs which included graphics as well as text, or form boxes, or something, I don't think it would immediately be considered off-topic. The fact that TeX cannot do what is asked should not, just in itself, make a difference.) Anyway, the OP's update clearly makes it on-topic.